# Display value based on selection in second activity android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to display different value using same activity file and XML file. I am able to display but don't know how to display value based on selection dynamically using array or something else. sorry for bad English please see images

[image]
**Activity 1:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    enableButtonEvents();
}

private void enableButtonEvents() {
    Button btnColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnColor);
    btnColor.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent colorIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(colorIntent);
        }
    });  

    Button btnAnimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnimal);
    btnAnimal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent animalIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(animalIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

**Activity 2:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);  
    }

    public void red(View view) throws InterruptedException {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
    } 

    public void black(View view) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
    }

    public void white(View view) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
    }

    public void yellow(View view) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
    }

    public void purple(View view) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
    }

    public void green(View view) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
    }

    public void blue(View view) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
    }

    public void brown(View view) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brown);
    }
}
```

**Xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="125sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/black"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:onClick="black"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/white"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:onClick="white"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/brown"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:onClick="brown"
        android:background="@color/brown"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:onClick="blue"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/brown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:onClick="red"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/brown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:onClick="green"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/blue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/red" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yellow"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:onClick="yellow"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:layout_marginRight="100sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/red" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/purple"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:onClick="purple"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/yellow"
        android:layout_below="@id/green" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**working Result :**

[image]

Comment: Is this related to "YOUR_KEY" ? should i define this key somwhere?

Comment: just edited another typo in the answer, kindly try to use it

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Intent` with extras to open Activity 2 when you press either color or animal button.

Example:

```
Button btnColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnColor);
    btnColor.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent colorIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            colorIntent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY", "colorIntent")
            startActivity(colorIntent);
        }
    });

Button btnColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnColor);
    btnColor.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent animalIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            animalIntent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY", "animalIntent")
            startActivity(animalIntent);
        }
    });
```

And then in your `Activity2` `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);  

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String key = intent.getStringExtra(YOUR_KEY);
    if(key.equals("animalIntent")) {
        btn1.setText("cat")
        //same for other buttons
    } else {
        btn1.setText("red")
        //same for other buttons
    } 
}
```

If you have problems with implementing example shown above, check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) training from developer.android.com

**EDIT:**
You also need to check the key in your button onClick action:

```
public void btn1(View view) {
    if(key.equals("animalIntent")) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
    } else {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly did not work for you? if there was an error, please specify it

Comment: I've used YOUR_KEY without quotes, cause usually the key is defined before (`String YOUR_KEY = "yourKey"`) and then use YOUR_KEY without quotes. But you can just use "YOUR_KEY" in quotes for key

Comment: what value was displayed?

Comment: try to use edited answer again, you probably use             `startActivity(colorIntent);` both times

Comment: edited my answer, check the link for more detailed guide on this

Comment: Thank you so much . it is worked with key.equals("animalIntent").

Comment: another problem is it is showing same image after clicking on button plz check public void btn1(View view)

Comment: you are setting the button color to the same one (e.g. you press red button and set button color to be red). are you trying to set whole background to button color?

Comment: It is not about button color . it is about image view where I am trying to display image based on selection.

Comment: Please check attached image in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and correct response.  I am new to stack overflow and found answer in very right place with right person. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Now everything is working. I am able to show different images as well .

```
    public class Main extends Activity {

    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drag);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String key = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        Button btn1,btn2;
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        if(key.equals("animalIntent") )
    {
        btn1.setText("cat");
        btn2.setText("dog");


    } else {
        btn1.setText("red");
        btn2.setText("blue");
    }
}

    public void btn1(View view) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String key = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
        if(key.equals("animalIntent") )
        {
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cat);
        } else {
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
        }
    }

    public void btn2(View view) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String key = intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");
        if(key.equals("animalIntent") )
        {
          image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dog);


        } else {
          image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
        }
    }
```